# Obtener las posiciones del array donde encuentre un valor con numpy.where

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo un array de la forma:

```
array = ['A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A']
```

Y necesito obtener las posiciones del array donde encuentre `'D'`. Lo que intento hacer es:

```
d_pos[numpy.where(array == 'D')]
```

Pero me da el siguiente fallo:

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Buscando he visto que `numpy.where` lo usan buscando valores numéricos, pero no me queda claro si también funciona buscando letras en este caso.

Y otra cosa, en realidad los valores en el array cuando los imprimo me aparecen en unicode, así:

```
array = [u'A', u'D', u'A', u'A', u'A', u'D', u'A', u'A', u'D', u'A']
```

Y no sé si el error es más bien por el formato o por el `numpy.where`

¿alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código hay varias cosas que parece que no están bien:

- Por una parte, para poder hacer la comparación de todos los elementos del `array` para saber si son igual a `'D'` necesitas que `array` sea realmente un `numpy.array`. Tal como lo estás definiendo es una lista.
- Por otra parte, `numpy.where` te devuelve una tupla con una `np.array` con las posiciones donde se cumple la condición y el `dtype` del `numpy.array`.

Si juntamos las dos cosas anteriores tenemos:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = ['A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A']
>>> print(np.where(array == 'D'))
(array([], dtype=int32),)
```

En el `numpy.where` estamos metiendo una condición que no se cumple, una lista pura de python no es igual a la cadena `'D'` y, por ello, `numpy.where` nos devuelve la tupla pero con el array de posiciones vacio.

En tu caso, a `d_pos` le estás pasando una tupla con la que indexar y el error te indica que no puedes usar tuplas para indexar.

Vamos a corregir levemente el código para ver si funciona:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array = np.array(['A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'D', 'A'])
>>> print(np.where(array == 'D'))
(array([1, 5, 8], dtype=int32),)
```

Ahora vemos con `np.where` ya nos devuelve una tupla que contiene el array de posiciones sin estar vacio. Si queremos usarlo en `d_pos` podemos hacer:

```
>>> indices = np.where(array == 'D')[0] # fíjate en el cero final
>>> d_pos[indices]
```

En la línea de `indices` me quedo con la primera parte de la tupla que me devuelve `np.where`, que es la que contiene las posiciones que estabas buscando.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Con tu explicación me he enterado bastante bien de cómo funcionan los numpy array para buscar en ellos, y he estado probando diferentes cosas para varios casos que necesitaba y todos han acabado funcionando perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya aclarado un poco su funcionamiento.